# Executing a new HttpServletRequest from a worker thread inside Jetty 9 server

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

My web app is based on (embedded) Jetty 9. The code that runs *inside* Jetty (i.e. from the *.war file) has the need to, at times, execute an HTTP request back into Jetty and itself, completely asynchronously to "real" HTTP requests coming from the network.

I know what you will say, but this is the situation I ended up with after merging multiple disparate products into one container and presently cannot avoid it. A stop-gap measure is in place - it actually sends a network HTTP request back to itself (presently using Jetty client, but that does not matter). However, not only that adds more overhead, it also does not allow us to pass actual object references we'd like to be able to pass via, say, request attributes.

Desire is to be able to do something like constructing new HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse pair and use a dispatcher to "include" (or similar) the other servlet we presently can only access via the network. We've built "dummy" implementations of those, but the this fails in Jetty's dispatcher line 120 with a null pointer exception:

```
public void include(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
  Request baseRequest=(request instanceof Request)?((Request)request):HttpChannel.getCurrentHttpChannel().getRequest();
```

... because this is *not* an instance of Jetty's Request class and getCurrentHttpChannel() returns null because the thread is a worker thread, not an http serving one and does not have Jetty's thread locals set up.

I am contemplating options, but would like some guidance if anyone can offer it. Some things I am thinking of:

1. Actually use Jetty's Request class as a base. Currently not visible to the web app (a container class, would have to play with classpath and class loaders perhaps. May still be impossible (don't know what to expect there).
2. Play with Jetty's thread locals, attempt to tell Jetty to set up current thread as necessary. Don't know where to begin. **UPDATE** Tried to setServerClasses([]) and then set the current HttpChannel to the one I 'stole' from another thread. Failed misearably: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.setCurrentHttpChannel(Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/HttpChannel;)V from class ...
3. Ideally, find a better/proper way of feeding a "top" request in without going via the network. Ideally would execute on the same thread, but I would be less concerned with that.

Remember that, unfortunately, I cannot avoid this at this time. I would much rather invoke code directly, but I cannot, as the code I had to add into mine is too big to handle at this time and too dependent on some third party filters I can't even modify (and only work as filters, on real requests).

Please help!